# my .load disappears fast

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my .click code that posts into database with ajax, and also shows and hides some elements, and now i've added functionality to load notification.php into div, but problem is , this loaded notification.php disappears in about 1 second, and more than that, i need to click twice on this button to show notification.php , any suggestions?

```
$("#notifBtn").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var dataString = 'name=' + name;
    var parent2 = $(".notifalert");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "voting/addnotif.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {

        } 
    });

    parent2.load("notification.php");
    $("#newpost").show();
    $(".thismenu").hide();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not sure If I understand, but what About using $(".thismenu").hide('slow');

Comment: no, with show () hide (), all works! main problem is with parent2.load("notification.php");

Comment: Shouldn't it be $parent2?

Comment: @SeanKendle see the 3rd variable declaration :)

Comment: @user2784722 Is the above code in a `document.ready` handler?  Can you also show us some relevant html?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `parent2.load` call in the success callback to `$.ajax`?

Comment: maybe there is some document.ready above, and yes, i tried to put into $.ajax (